# Oracle select last record for a particular id

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table in oracle 11g like this:

```
id   date  
---  ---
1    1-jun
1    2-jun
1    3-jun
2    1-jul
2    2-jul
2    3-jul
```

I am trying to extract the latest record corresponding to each id. I tried group by, max but I cannot get it to work. What I want is:

```
   id    date 
   ---   ---
    1    3-jun
    2    3-jul
```

Comment: What is the column type for your date? `SELECT id, MAX(date) FROM table GROUP BY id` works for me.

Comment: It is varchar2 but when i do: SELECT id, MAX(to_date(date,'yyyy-mm-dd') FROM table GROUP BY id; i get multiple records per id. Not the latest one.

Comment: I found it here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql

Thank you for your replies

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, MAX(date)
  FROM <YOUR-TABLE>
 GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
'SELECT *FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date   DESC )tmp GROUP BY Id ';
```